# What version of JaspeReports has support for Java 8?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, compatibility, java-8

I have been searching for quite some time to read an "official statement" on this matter, but found none. Therefore, could anyone please indicate a reference or point to some news on this? What version of JasperReports has support for Java 8, or at least is there partial support available? (or is it "trial and error"?)

Some posts on the Jasper community forum seem to indicate that iReport and JasperReports Server does not provide Java 8 support yet. On the other hand, I see some indications that it does, at least in part (http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/3498). It is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as i know, JasperReport does not support Java 8 yet, just like you said. In this post a member of JasperSoft staff clearly states that they will introduce it on later versions of their library, so i would trust him: [JasperReport - Java 8 compatibility](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824715/ireport-compatibility-java8).

Comment: Yes, apparently no word on this even in the just released JasperReports 5.5.2. Seems we either wait or "trial and error" it.

Answer (score 6):

We are not aware of any issue with running JasperReports Library on Java 8.

At some point we needed to upgrade the JDT compiler to support Java 8, but after doing so, there were no other issues we know about.

Comment: Teodor, What is planning date of release with *Java 8* support?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Teodor. I trust others will find this useful also.

Comment: Alex, JR Lib already works with Java 8. Have you tried it and it did not work?

Comment: @TeodorDanciu `At some point we needed to upgrade the JDT compiler to support Java 8, but after doing so, there were no other issues we know about.` - What do you mean?

Comment: What I meant is that the only Java 8 related problem that we know about was that the JDT compiler version 3.1.1 that we were using prior to JR 6.0.0 did not support Java 8. We use a Java compiler to produce bytecode out of the expressions inside JRXML templates. Starting with JR 6.0.0 we upgraded the JDT compiler to version 4.3.1 (now known as Eclipse Java Compiler) and there should be no issue running JR Lib on Java 8.

Comment: JasperReports Server 6.0.1 on Java 8u102 start up error: `.... Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory: jar:file:/home/jasperreports/jasperserver-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib/saxonhe-9.2.1.5.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax`

Comment: @TeodorDanciu, I might have hit the same issue which you had. Have you seen any problem after upgrading the JDT version keeping the same version of JR?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Java 8 support jasper report i am using jasperreport version 6.0.0 with java 8 and it is working as per expectation

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.