# Which ireport version corresponds to which jasperreport version?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I had a .jasper and .jrxml file which i edit it with ireport 5 but after compiling it doesn't work. I use `jasperreports-lib 5.5.0` java 1.8 and intellij IDE
i get following error in my project.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2313)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2326)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2797)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:244)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:229)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:632)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:956)
    at de.devb.reports.action.PrintOffLine.print(PrintOffline.java:80)
```

Does anybody know version compatibility of ireport and jasperreport library?
How to detect ireport version used from .jasper .jrxml file?

Comment: The versions should be the same. If you download `iReport-5.5.1.zip`, for example, and extract it, there should be a file called `jasperreports-5.5.1.jar` located under `/iReport-5.5.1/ireport/modules/ext/`

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. It's a valid question, specific, un-opinionated question

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ireport 5.5 to compile your report, you java code need to depends this .jar version.
Case you product you jrxml with one version and compile jrxml with another older version, in some cases jasperreports will throw a exception. Check this

Comment: what kind of exception might it throw in that case?

Comment: java lang null when java try to search the UUID element inside every field in .jrxml.
[check this image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32169037/Capturar.PNG)

Answer (score 1):

Just check the Java version, here you have mentioned Java1.8, your jasperreport version will not support Java8.
There is one more thread here
[What version of JaspeReports has support for Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315545/what-version-of-jaspereports-has-support-for-java-8)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to each version's changelog to see jasperreport compability:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport/

And here for (even) older versions:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport%20%28classic%29/