# Use lambda expressions inside TextField expression in Jaspersoft Studio 6.3

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I want to use lambda expressions inside a TextField expression like this:

```
Arrays.asList($F{field1}, $F{field2}, $F{field3}).stream().filter(i -> i != null).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" / "))
```

Assuming this values for the fields:

```
$F{field1} = 1
$F{field2} = null
$F{field3} = 2
```

The expected result is of the TextField evaluation is:

```
1 / 2
```

Instead of I'm getting an error in the IDE:

```
Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
```

And this is the exception inside the IDE during the compile:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
                value = "Contato: " + Arrays.asList(((java.lang.String)field_c_telefone.getValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_celular.getValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_fax.getValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_email.getValue())).stream().filter(i -> i != null).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" / ")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=22$
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               <------------>
2. Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
                value = "Contato: " + Arrays.asList(((java.lang.String)field_c_telefone.getOldValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_celular.getOldValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_fax.getOldValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_email.getOldValue())).stream().filter(i -> i != null).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" / ")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=22$
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <------------>
3. Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
                value = "Contato: " + Arrays.asList(((java.lang.String)field_c_telefone.getValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_celular.getValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_fax.getValue()), ((java.lang.String)field_c_email.getValue())).stream().filter(i -> i != null).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" / ")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=22$
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               <------------>
3 errors
.

    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:206)

    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:294)

    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:146)

    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportsBuilder.compileJRXML(JasperReportsBuilder.java:220)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction.actionCompile(CompileAction.java:142)

    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction$1.run(CompileAction.java:93)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I already changed my report project to use the JRE System 1.8, but the error continues.

How can I solve it? Does jasper compiler supports lambdas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable *Java 8* support try to add this 3 parameters to the *Jaspersoft Studio.ini* file (placed at *`\TIBCO\Jaspersoft Studio-6.x.final`* folder):

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

My ini file looks like this (for *Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1* version):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-data
@noDefault
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
features/jre.win32.win32.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u92/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

I checked this report and it compiled and worked well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="java8support" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="p1" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p2" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["2"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="20" width="234" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($P{p1}, $P{p2}).stream().filter(i -> i != null).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" / "))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Compiling result:

[image: Result of compiling in JSS]

The generated result in *JSS*:

[image: Preview in JSS]

#### Remark

I got the same error (`Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above`) without using this 3 parameters in *JSS*:

[image: Error during compiling in JSS]

---

#### More info how to compile templates from *Java* project in posts:

- [How to use lambda expression in jrxml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38275384/876298)
- [What version of JaspeReports has support for Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566807/876298)
- [Does JDK 8 supports JasperReports 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958694/876298)