# iReports is not work with JDK 8?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have some issue here,
I searched it and got that iReport Designer cannot working with JDK 8.
but I need to using method on my project that using JDK 8.
if I use my method it will give a warning.

> `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

is there any solution for it? so I can run my method?

Comment: Are you able to use Jaspersoft Studio?

Comment: no, because my company project is using iReport and I am fresh here @AlexK

Comment: The iReport is deprecated, it is better to use Studio. For Studio you can look at this post: [Use lambda expressions inside TextField expression in Jaspersoft Studio 6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41618362/876298)

Comment: Thanks @AlexK I will consider about this with my team

Answer (score 1):

As Alex already said, iReport Designer is deprecated and will not be supported any further.

Since version 5.5 Jaspersoft Studio is the official and **supported** Client for Jaspersoft.

In Jaspersoft Studio you can choose which version of jasper-reports you want to use:

[image]